# how to create a user in oracle using SQL*PLUS by running a script from txt file that will prompt me for 2 parameters (username, password)

Tags: oracle, parameters, passwords, sqlplus

I have a question about creating users in Oracle using SQL*PLUS. But what I want to do is write the syntax in a txt file first (script) then when I run the script by calling it using the @ or by copy/past it should prompt me for two parameters (user name and a password). I searched through the web and read 2 books and I still can't find the right syntax.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `ACCEPT` command to prompt the user for an input (but it's not really necessary if you use substitution variables that are prefixed with the `&` character.

Details are in the manual:
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b31189/ch5.htm#CACIFHGB

If you want to customize the message displayed to the user when entering the value, you can use the `ACCEPT` command.

Again details are in the manual:
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b31189/ch12005.htm#BACGJIHF